# chaining animation - new location doesn't persist between animations

Tags: android

**Problem:**

after the move-down animation completes, the textview is positioned back to its original location and then rotates.

**Desired Effect:**

the textview moves down the screen, then rotates forever at its location

**XML Layout**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    tools:context=".ActivityMain">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_hello"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**move.XML :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator">

    <!-- move down -->
    <translate
        android:duration="800"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:fromYDelta="0%p"
        android:startOffset="0"
        android:toYDelta="70%p" />

</set>
```

**rotate.XML :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillBefore="true"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">

    <!-- infinite rotate -->
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:toDegrees="360"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:duration="1200" />

</set>
```

**Java Code :**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ActivityMain extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView mTextView;
    private Animation mAnimationMove;
    private Animation mAnimationRotate;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_hello);

        mAnimationMove = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(ActivityMain.this, R.anim.move);
        mAnimationRotate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(ActivityMain.this, R.anim.rotate);

        mAnimationMove.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                mTextView.startAnimation(mAnimationRotate);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {

            mTextView.startAnimation(mAnimationMove);

            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

HOW CAN THIS BE DONE ??
It's incredible that something so seemingly easy is actually quite difficult !

Comment: Can you out both animations into the same XML/set but have the second animation have a start offset the length of the first animation?

Comment: no it's not possible because if I have it move first and then rotate in the same XML, the pivot for rotation will be the *original* starting location. Which is completely undesirable.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter="true"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator">

<!-- move down -->
<translate
    android:duration="800"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:fromYDelta="0%p"
    android:startOffset="0"
    android:toYDelta="70%p" />

</set>
```

to this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter="true"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator">

<!-- move down -->
<translate
    android:duration="800"
    android:fillEnabled="true"
    android:fromYDelta="0%p"
    android:startOffset="0"
    android:toYDelta="70%p" />

 </set>
```

Comment: but I want it to move first and then rotate

Comment: sorry, i misunderstood your question, try the new one.